# How to find all tables updated by a particular plsql method

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any way to find all which tables are (potentially) updated by a particular PLSQL method, other than by code inspection?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.

`ALL_DEPENDENCIES` lists the tables statically referenced by a PL/SQL package but that will include both tables read and tebles updated, and it's for the entire package, not just a single procedure. Tables updated via dynamic SQL are not listed. Also, a procedure can call procedures outside the package, and they can in turn update additional tables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe query the all_source table:

```
select * from  all_source
where name = 'procedure_name'
and upper(text) like upper('%update TABLE_NAME%');
```

While not exactly what you want, it will show what procedures, functions or packages contain the table_name right after an UPDATE (assuming they are on the same line).